# How to make letters from numbers

Tags: php, function

I would like to change number (ie. 19455) into something shorter using numbers and digits (ie. w3b) so for example number 19455 is replaced by w3b. I would like to be able to get back that number when I enter w3b. Is there a ready function that I could use or do I have to build it by myself?

Comment: what process you use to transform 19445 to w3b?

Comment: Do you have specific 'short forms', ie., 19455 should be only 'w3b' and so on? Else you can use any conversion algorithm to convert from decimal to say, hexadecimal, so the numbers become shorter and convertible back to decimal.

Comment: @RageZ: Apparently, 'w3b' is a random string OP provided as an example. All he needs is to convert to alphanumeric so it will be shorter, is what I think.

Comment: w3b is a random string, it is not related to 19445 whatsoever :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `base_convert` php function:

Example:

```
$myNumInDecimal = "1234567787";
$myNumInBase36 = base_convert($myNumInDecimal, 10, 36);
```

this will give you:

```
kf12ln
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

BUT notice that both to and from bases should be between 2..36.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for however It would be nice to use A-Z letters as well.

Comment: @debianek: It _does_ use A-Z letters depending on the base, as you see the maximum base is 36 because 0..9 + A..Z = 10 + 26 = 36 :)

Comment: Aha I see now what you meant, apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to a function that convert your number which are in decimal to hexadecimal , that will make a good solution I guess

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will do...

```
     <?
     # MAKE STRING INTO ARRAY TO FOR NUMBERS 0-9
   $numbers = array();
   for($counter =0; $counter <= 10; $counter++) {
       $numbers[$counter] = $counter;
    }


                 # FUNCTION TO CHANGE NUMBER INTO LETTERS
     function change_to_letters($string) {
    global $numbers;
  $replacements = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j");
     $string = str_replace($numbers, $replacements, $string);
  return $string;
 }
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo 'I changed '.$_POST['string'].' to this:<div style="border: 1px solid          #666;background-  color:                                                                #E6FAD9;width:200px;padding:5px;">'.change_to_letters($_POST['string']).'</div>';
          }

          ?>

   <!-- INPUT FORM --->
         <form action="" method="post">
           Enter some numbers here and i will change them into letters:<br /><input           name="string" type="text" size="15" maxlength="10"><br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert"><br />
     </form>
```

Comment: Example:- Enter some numbers here and i will change them into letters: 123,  OUTPUT: bcd

Comment: I thought it is the program code that 'will change'! You can edit the answer to include your comment.

Comment: Please see the `strtr` function and the `range` function.